# log4net doesn't log in Windows Event Viewer

Tags: c#, log4net, event-log, event-viewer

I would like to log in the Windows Event Viewer using log4net.
I created a Console Application (.NET Framework 4), I added the reference log4net.dll, I put the following code in my App.config:

```xml
<configuration>
 <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
 </configSections>

<log4net>
<appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender"/>
</root>
</log4net>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup>
</configuration>
```

And I put the following code :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
        log.Error("test error", new Exception("error's exception", new Exception("error's innerexception")));

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

It doesn't log, nothing happens, why?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to call [configure](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure_overload_5.html).

Change:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "App.config", Watch = true)]
```

To

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

When you specify `ConfigFile = "App.config"` its going to look for App.config but your filename would be `[FileName].Config`.

Comment: I'm under an administrator account. I tried to run my app as admin, same problem. I tried to reboot visual studio as admin, same result.

Comment: Do you have a configure statement ?

Comment: like this ? [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "App.config", Watch = true)] 
i used the default App.config, i tried to put this in AssemblyInfo.cs, same result.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call **XmlConfigurator.Configure** from the log4net library to initialize it. (see below)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // you need this
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
        log.Error("test error", new Exception("error's exception", new Exception("error's innerexception")));

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call XmlConfigurator.Configure() at the begining of your App.

You also need to grant the user running the application rights to put data in the eventlog.

A good way to do this is with powershell, admin mode

```
  New-EventLog EventLogName -source ApplicationName
```

Also, add this two parameters into the appender

```
  <param name="LogName" value="EventLogName " />
  <param name="ApplicationName" value="ApplicationName" />
```

Regards,